# Remove gap at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get rid of the gap between the top of the page and the blue div? Please note that bootstrap is loaded.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #444;
}
#root {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='root'>
  <h1>Header Header</h1>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/wasteland/pen/qqOddN

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `margin: 0` on the `h1`.

[revised codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNdpzE)

Basically, you need to override the top margin applied to the `h1` from three different sources:

[image]